# Create a calendar from scratch

Tags: android

My aim is to create a calendar from scratch that displays 30 days as onclickable values so when a user presses the 2nd it should display fields where the user can type information. It would then store it into a SQLite table.

I thought about some solutions. I can make a calendar by creating textview with 30 buttons for each month, but that would be slightly ridiculous.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use buttons as GridView  elements to create calender onClick event should be handled within the adapter this would be the easiest approach to this problem